# Point of sale products load and add to cart or html table in asp.net C# Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to develop the POS System, I need to load products and add 
    it to html table or cart. in server side i Loaded the products but for adding 
    a product to html table I am using Jquery. please help me in this.

This is Markup

```
     <div class="content-top">
            <h1>
                Recent Products</h1>

             <div class="content-top1">
                <% 
                    if (products_list.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var prod in products_list)
                        { 
                %>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-md2">
                    <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="<%=prod.img %>" alt="" />
                        </a>
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#" id="ItemName">
                                <%=prod.name%></a></h3>
                        <div class="price">
                            <h5 class="item_price">
                                <%=prod.price%></h5>

                             <a href="#" class="item_add" id="AddTo">Add To Cart</a
                            <div class="clearfix">
                            </div>
                               <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                Add To List <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                <%}
                    }
                    else
                    {

                %>
                <h2>
                    No Products Available!</h2>
                <%} %>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
            </div>
        </div>
             <table id="tbl" class="table table-hover tbl" style="font-size: 11px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Select
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Jquery function: this is function that I am using it for adding product to html table or cart.

```
       $(function () {

            $('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                    var ItemName = $('#ItemName').html();
                    var Price = $('.item_price').html();

                    var markup = "<tr><td><span>" + ItemName + "</span></td><td><span>" + Price + "</span></td></tr>";


                    $("#tbl tbody").append(markup);

            });
       });
```

[Products List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILIue.png)

Comment: You haven't formulated a question or a concrete problem in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. But there's a problem I noticed in your template. The id of the button "Add to List" is getting duplicated.

```
<button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
```

You cannot have multiple elements with the same id on a page. It will broke processing of the `$("#btnAdd").click` handler.

To fix this, remove the id for the button, you don't need it. Use class instead. Something like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-add">
...
$('.btn-add').click(function (e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, Suppose I have products list from database and adding that to cart. something like shown in an image. and the second point when I am using the (class) for button it just add the first product to the HTML table list or cart. I attached the image above

Comment: @Farmanullah "it's just add the first product to the HTML table list or cart", my answer is exactly about how to fix this. The problem is duplicated id.